# Make use of design patterns in C?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, c

Design patterns are useful for object oriented languages.

But how can a **non-object-oriented** language such as **C** make of use them?

Comment: Languages like C need design patterns even more, as one of the primary reasons why they exist at all is because of inadequacies of the underlying language.

Comment: You *can* write object-oriented code in C or even in assembly. It's just that it's a ton of work. It's relatively easy to write C programs with public interfaces but private implementation (encapsulation). Inheritance and polymorphism are possible too, but have to write a ton of boiler-plate code for every data structure that you want to support them.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Actually, it is not that hard to implement inheritance & polymorphism, simply use [opaque types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer). Bit more crude than languages with OO support but gets the job done.

Comment: @Yousha If you believe that there are object-oriented and non-object-oriented languages, you haven't grasped what object orientation means. There are languages with _support for OO features_. No code automatically turns object-oriented because you write it in C++ or Java, nor does it automatically turn object-oriented because you use the class keyword. Object-orientation is quite language-independent. The most important features are modular design, encapsulation and inheritance. The former two has little to do with the language, but a lot to do with the program design.

Comment: _Design Patterns_ are just proven solution to common _Problems_. OOP itself is a form Design Pattern where you create the concept of _Object_ in your software for certain benefits. Some patterns might make more sense in OOP languages, however that doesn't stop the non-OOP languages to make use of it.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but I'd like to mention a book I liked a lot: http://www.amazon.com/21st-Century-Tips-New-School/dp/1449327141

It addresses quite a few of the "issues" C has vs more modern languages.

Comment: Non-OOP languages use different [patterns](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/67594/non-oop-design-patterns/67623#67623)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To reinforce the answers already given, a quote from GOF Design Patterns book itself:

> Our patterns assume Smalltalk/C++-level language features, and that choice determines what can and cannot be implemented easily. If we assumed procedural languages, we might have included design patterns called "Inheritance", "Encapsulation" and "Polymorphism".

While the design patterns described there are geared towards object-oriented software, and certainly object-oriented programming languages are a natural fit for it, the concepts they embody are language agnostic. What varies is the work overhead you would have to invest to implement the required OOP feature or a workaround for it.

Comment: +1. You could also say that many of the design patterns are implementation overhead themselves for missing features in common OOP language implementations..

Comment: @Macke: Good point. As an example, the visitor pattern is used with OOP languages that only provide single-dispatch.

Comment: How can I undetstand this quote? Why for procedural languages, we might have included design patterns called "Inheritance", "Encapsulation" and "Polymorphism"? Aren't they features of an object-oriented language? How can they be included in procedural languages by us?

Comment: Yes, in OOP languages these concepts are baked into the language itself. In other languages that don't have those features, you can still express the concepts in terms of the features the language has. If this solution is abstract and reproducible in other contexts - you can call it a design pattern. Example: [encapsulation design pattern in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119284/data-encapsulation-in-c).

Answer (score 8):

From the wikipedia article on [Software design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern):

> a design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design

As you can see, there is no mention of object oriented programming here.

Design patterns apply to any computer language and sometimes are higher level (architectural patterns).

One example is for SQL - there is a even a book for [SQL Design Patterns](http://www.rampant-books.com/book_0601_sql_coding_styles.htm).

Answer (score 7):

Design patterns are not limited to certain languages or language families. You could come up with design patterns for any language or paradigm.

If you are referring to the GOF patterns: Have a look at `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin`in C. That's the strategy pattern which does not seem so OO after all.

BTW:
Object Oriented Programming is not language dependend. Some languages make it easier, some make it harder, but you can program "object oriented" in any universal (as in 'not special purpose' like e.g. SQL) language.

Comment: Excuse me, how are stdout/stderr/stdin instances of the strategy pattern? They are just global variables. Sure, you can replace them to change where certain functions write to/read from, but that's pretty basic stuff and a way to avoid lots and lots of extra parameters.

Comment: @delnan He is referring to the concept of standard output/error/input streams in C, and not the global variables with the same name.

Comment: @OskarN. I'm afraid I don't follow. How does the concept of having a couple of streams for everyone to write to have anything to do with the strategy pattern, which is a design pattern by which an implementation of an algorithm is chosen at runtime?

Comment: @delnan The concept of standard output/error/input streams is that your application can write to `stdout` and read from `stdin` without concern where this is actually read from/written to. When your application is running, `stdin` could be redirected to read from a TCP socket, and `stdout` could be redirected to write directly to a printer (for example)

Comment: You two must be defining the strategy pattern awfully broad then. To me, that's just basic use of variables. So basically everything where a nontrivial effect depends on the value of some storage location (and is not explicitly decided via branching by the causing code) is the strategy pattern?

Comment: @delnan Sure, why not? Strategy pattern in C++ using polymorphism is just variables as well (exchange the object pointer). Any behavior/algorithm that can be exchanged at run-time without changing the client interface is the strategy pattern.

Comment: The strategy pattern: OO languages: polymorphism; prodedural languages: variables; functional languages: functions (doh!)

Comment: Oskar N. is right. As delnan noted, the pattern is about choice of an implementation (strategy) at runtime and that is what you do with the standard output/error/input streams in C. The user of stdout does not need to know and should not know where its output is written.